# Is it possible to simulate 3D touch in macmini?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I am using mac mini for application development. I am aware with the apple's 3D Touch and its availability on simulator as well.

But I think its simulation is available with MacBook only using a Force Touch trackpad.

Is it possible to simulate 3D touch in simulator with macmini?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm aware you can't do this in any simulates.It isn't supported.

Comment: I doubt that as because Xcode has option Hardware -> Use Trackpad Force for 3D Touch. Kindly refer to release notes of Xcode 7.3

Comment: @cjd I test on my MacBook Pro and it's there,you're right.I suggest you buy a single trackpad to test on Mac mini.

Comment: @cjd And you should buy the latest trackpad which supports force touch.

Comment: @ Lumialxk Thanks for checking. Buy the latest trackpad is obviously the solution. I just wanted to confirm that whatever I researched with MacMini is correct.